# Scala DSL - Simple Math

Tags: scala, math, dsl

I'm relatively new at Scala and I'm struggling with DSLs. Currently I'm trying to implement a simple Math DSL which could be used with some kind of natural language.

My Idea:

print(Calculate 4 plus 6)=> returns 10

print(Calculate 4 mins 2)=> returns 2
... and so on

So far I have implemented two classes. The main class which serves just for calling the method and a calculation class. My Problem is a have no Idea how I could pass the first number to the calculation object, because It is not allowed to define parameters.

Could Anyone Help with an example or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to run into some troubles making this feel like a natural language since the natural form that Scala wants to parse is `class-instance method argument method argument method argument ...`, which is rather unlike English.

However, here is a framework to get you started, with lots of extra boilerplate syntax to make the parsing work out right.

```
object Now {
  class Value(val please: Double) {
    def plus(d: Double) = new Value(please + d)
    def minus(d: Double) = new Value(please - d)
    override def toString = please.toString
  }
  def calculate(d: Double): Value = new Value(d)
}
```

And here it is working (after an `import language.postfixOps`):

```
scala> Now calculate 4 plus 6 please
res1: Double = 10.0
```

Incidentally, there's already a very good natural way to ask for 4+6...it's `4+6`.  It works for speakers of many different languages, and for almost all computer languages too.  So this DSL might be fun for a toy, but I'm not sure what the practical utility is.

Comment: You can call it "Polite Arithmetic," though personally I prefer to take a dictatorial approach to dealing with computers…

Comment: Hey thanks for your help! Actually it was just for practicing purposes =). Do you know any more relevant but simple DSLs to start with?

Comment: @user3042626 - ScalaTest has a very English-like DSL.